# Unexpected error from external database driver while importing file

Tags: c#, excel

when i try to import excel in winform application(C#) i got error.

Error Message -> "Unexpected error from external database driver"

Comment: [Some insights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10421914/1997232).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting an Unexpected error from external database driver (1) when importing data from excel to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421914/getting-an-unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-1-when-importing-dat)

Comment: I am trying to import data in infragistic grid

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the latest Microsoft update ([KB4041687](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4041687/windows-81-update-kb4041687)). A couple of our customers had this problem this morning. The update seems to have had a somewhat adverse effect on the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver with regard to Excel connections. This is just one of many problems with this particular update.

[See article here.](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3232095/microsoft-windows/microsoft-patch-problems-persist-bad-release-sequences-crm-blocks-and-more.html)

I advised our customers to roll back the update and everything started working again. Obviously this is a temporary solution but until such time as a fix is available it's all I could advise.